Can I DELETE FROM table B using Soft Deletion on Table A? Many To Many
My example classes:
@Entity
@Table
@SoftDelete
public class Person {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Appointment {
 private Integer id;
 private LocalDate date;
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appointment")
 private List<AppointmentPerson> persons;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class AppointmentPerson {
 @ManyToOne
 private Appointment appointment;
 @ManyToOne
 private Person person;
 private boolean confirmed;
}

When I delete one person, it only updates the "deleted" column to true, this is right.
But I want to cascade the deletion to all appointments that this person was linked, something like DELETE FROM appointment_person WHERE person_id = ?, because the way it is now the appointments of this "deleted" person are persisted, and when I try to find the appointment, it throws error:
Entity "Person" with identifier value "1" does not exist
Actually I'm using a trigger that does the job, but I want to know if there's anything not DB dependent.
Already tried to put in class Person:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<AppointmentPerson> appointments

but nothing happened :/

Why you need 3 classes mapping did you try with only 2 classes ?

@Mr_Thorynque I have other fields in the 3rd class, it was only an example.
fields like LocalTime checkIn; LocalTime checkOut;

Maybe FK constraints block delete operation. What id in AppointmentPerson class ?
